# AngularJS with signalR service not working on server call

Tags: angularjs, signalr, angular-services, signalr.client

I am trying to create service for chat in my app. This is my code for signalR angular service. What i want to do is to not repeat my code, i want to keep creating another functions like in the first non-working case but i didnt figure out how to get it done. Can someone tell me where is problem or what are the differences between those two types of returns. In both cases its initialized but only on the second one it catch calls from server side. I didnt include Hub because there is nothing related to this problem

```
(function () {
app.service("SignalRService", ["$rootScope", SignalRService]);
"use strict";
function SignalRService($rootScope) {
    //this is not working version
    return {
        channelHub: null,
        initialize: function () {
            //var chatHub = $.connection.channelHub;
            var connection = $.hubConnection();
            this.channelHub = connection.createHubProxy('channelHub');
            // Start Hub
            connection.start().done(function () { });
        },
        getMsg: function (eventName, callback) {
            this.channelHub.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(this.channelHub, args);
                })
            })
            console.log(eventName);
        }
    }
    //but if i retype it like this its working w/o any problem
    return {      
        getMsg: function (eventName, callback) {
            var connection = $.hubConnection();
            var channelHub = connection.createHubProxy('channelHub');

            channelHub.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(channelHub, args);
                });
            });
            connection.start().done(function () { });
        }
    };
}})();
```

Here is my angular controller, where i call servis initialize function and according to debuger and console log, function "newChannelMessage is initialized and no error is thrown

```
(function () {
app.controller("ChannelController", ["$scope", "$http", "SignalRService" ]);
function ChannelController($scope, $http, SignalRService) {
    "use strict";
    //**--------------------signalR--------------------------------**//
    SignalRService.initialize();
    SignalRService.getMsg("newChannelMessage", function (message, username) {
        $scope.channel.push(message, username);
    });
}})();
```

Here is my server controller where i call "newChannelMessage" function but it never reach this function in client-side and nothing rly happen in first case of my implemented method

```
    public class CommentController : BaseApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private CommentRepository _repository;
    private IHubContext _ctx;

    public CommentController()
    {
        //initialize of db context
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _repository = new CommentRepository();
        _ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChannelHub>();
    }

    [Route("create")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task SendMsg([FromBody] JObject data)
    {
        var channelId = data["idData"].ToObject<int>();
        Comment comment = data["channelMsgData"].ToObject<Comment>();
        comment.UserId = await GetIdUsingUsername(comment.UserName);         
        await _repository.StoreChannelMessage(comment, channelId);
        _ctx.Clients.All.newChannelMessage(comment.Message, comment.UserName);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetIdUsingUsername(string username)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == username);
        var id = user.Id;
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
function SignalRService($rootScope) {

            var connection = null;
            var channelHub = null;

            var initialize = function () {
                connection = $.hubConnection();
                channelHub = connection.createHubProxy('channelHub');
                connection.start().done(function () {
                    console.log("Hub started");
                });
            }

            var getMsg = function (eventName, callback) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                channelHub.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(channelHub , args);
                    });
                });
            }


            return {
                initialize: initialize,
                getAllUsers: getAllUsers
            }
}
```